# Post Link with custom type

Tags: wordpress, pagination

How can I use `next_post_link` with a custom type in Wordpress?

Answer (score 4):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/next-post-link-on-custom-taxonomy ? ;-)